# thread safety concerns for generic parameters on concurrent collections

Tags: c#, concurrency

When using `System.Collections.Concurrent`, what should I be aware of for the contained items?

For instance:
`ConcurrentDictionary<int,HashSet<string>>` vs `ConcurrentDictionary<int,ConcurrentBag<string>>`

The hashset may be desireable because of its behavior... but its not contained in the safe concurrent collections space.  So do I need to worry that multiple threads may write to a contained hashset at once... or will those accesses be managed within the context of the concurrent dictionary in a thread safe manner?  MSDN states that instance members of HashSet are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Please explain the implications and provide guidance.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concurrent collections do no synchronization for access to the contained items.
How could they?

For example:

```
var myValue = myDictionary[myKey];
... I can now do what I want with myValue without the dictionary being aware of it.
```

In your case you must implement your own synchronization for access to the HashSet.